# Incompatible data types when importing Excel spreadsheet into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-import-wizard

I want to import a spreadsheet from Excel into an existing SQL Server 2012 table. I use SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.

Here is the create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions
(
    payer_id int,
    order_number int,
    sum_units int,
    sum_value float(8),
    id_3rd_level int,
    order_date date,
    isCorporate int, 
    payment char(20),
    tk int

    PRIMARY KEY(id_3rd_level) 
);
```

After choosing the destination table for the spreadsheet, in "edit mappings" option, I choose the "destination" that corresponds to the "source" for each column. When I click next there is a yellow triangle for each column with an error message like this "Potential lost conversion from Double to int".

Any idea about how can I avoid incompatible types?

Comment: You may lose fraction part `1.2` -> `1`

Comment: But how can I avoid incompatible types?

Comment: You aren't telling us which columns are flagged, but if you have a floating point number in the worksheet and you are mapping it to an int in the database then you will lose the fractional part of the cell contents due to truncation. You can change the data type of the table attribute to match what you are importing. If you can't change the schema, then add a column to the worksheet that converts your troublesome column to the target data type and import that column instead.

Comment: All columns are flagged. Int and float culumns are supposed to be Double and char columns are supposed to be VarChar